# Number of isolated vertices in 10-regular bipartite graph after random edge deletion - estimating probability of large devation

Tags: probability

The problem states as follows:

> Let $G$ be some 10-regular bipartite graph with $2*10^6$ vertices. Every edge of $G$ is deleted with probability of $2^{-0,1}$, independent of other edges. Prove that the number of isolated vertices after this deletion will be in interval $[10^6-10^4,10^6+10^4]$ with probability at least $0,9999$

It's easy to show, that if $I$ is number of isolated vertices, then $E[I]=10^6$, and we're counting $1-P(|I-E[I]|\geq 10^4)$ and we can upper-bound $P(|I-E[I]|\geq 10^4)$ using Chebyshev inequality, the problem is that doing that, we get approximation of about $0,92 \leq P(|I-E[I]|<10^4)$, so it's to weak by two orders of magnitude... So the problem asks us to do something more clever than straightforward Chebyshev approximation. What are some other techniques I could use? Chernoff bound, for example, seems like a no-go as it doesn't seem that we could split $I$ into sum of independent 0/1 random variables... Any tips?

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, I got the number wrong... Yes, I meant $2^{-0.1}$, and by the way, by evaluating Chebyshev bound exactly using Python I get lower-bound of $0,991$, so it's almost there, but we clearly need to use something else....

Comment: Consider all vertices on one side of the graph. They become isolated independently of each other - so you can apply Normal approximation to their sum. Same for the other side. Adding them up the worst will happen if correlation is $1$ (that is variance quadruples rather than doubles as in case of independence). This should give you desired accuracy.